# How to factor polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I am wondering if there is a methodical, algorithmic, brain-dead way to factor polynomials. For example:

$x^6 - 14x^{5} + 73x^{4} - 188x^{3} + 256x^{2} - 176x^{1} + 48$

can be written as

$(x-1)^2 (x-2)^3 (x-6)$

But how do you actually get there?

Comment: This one can be solved using the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and polynomial division.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26135/is-factoring-polynomials-as-hard-as-factoring-integers.

Comment: The first thing to realise is that although the word "factor" might seem clear, it is actually ambiguous.  You need to specify whether factorisations such as$$x^2-2=(x-\sqrt2)(x+\sqrt2)\quad\hbox{and}\quad x^2+2=(x-\sqrt{-2})(x+\sqrt{-2})\ ,$$and many other such, are allowed.

Comment: @David I am trying to learn how to solve recurrences which can involve factoring in this way, so I would say those kinds of solutions are allowed (for example, the Fibonacci recurrence uses $1-x-x^2$), unless I am mistaken

Comment: There are none, in general. For most polynomials factorization, just like root-finding, is a very hard problem: only numerical methods are always available.

Comment: @A.P. So on the backend of something like Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha, would it likely be using something like numeric methods for complicated polynomials?

Comment: No need for anything really complicated: most irreducible polynomials of degree $\geq 5$ will trigger numerical results, e.g. [$x^7+x+1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E7%2Bx%2B1). See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of factoring polynomials is in general difficult and/or labor-intensive, but for the sake of concreteness, I'll indicate one way to factor the example polynomial that uses a few methods (caution: these methods do not apply to all polynomials!).

The Rational Root Theorem says that any (reduced form) rational root $\frac{s}{t}$ of a polynomial $$p(x) := a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$$ satisfies $s \mid a_0$ and $t \mid a_n$. In particular, if the polynomial is monic (i.e., $a_n = 1$) any rational root is in fact an integer, and all such roots are factors of $a_0$. In our case, the possible integer roots of
$$q(x) := x^6 - 14x^{5} + 73x^{4} - 188x^{3} + 256x^{2} - 176x + 48$$
are just the factors of $48$.

There are, unfortunately, 20 of these (counting sign), but we can simplify our search considerably by observing that the signs of the coefficients of $q(x)$ alternate with degree, and hence the signs of $q(-x)$ are all the same (in this case positive). So, $q(-0) > 0$ and $q(-x)$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$; hence all of the roots of $q(-x)$ are negative, or equivalently, all of the roots of $q(x)$ (rational or otherwise) are positive, reducing the list of integers to check by one-half.

If we start with the largest factors of $a_0 = 48$ and work down, we find that the largest root of $q$ is $6$, and so $(x - 6)$ is a factor of $q(x)$. Polynomial long division gives that
$$q(x) = (x - 6) r(x) ,$$ where $$r(x) := x^5-8 x^4+25 x^3-38 x^2+28 x-8,$$
and we can see that by starting with the largest factors of $a_0$ we produce the smallest constant terms after polynomial long division, reducing more the list of possibilities to check at the next step. Indeed, $8$ only has four positive factors to check. (Of course, if you're checking this without calculator assistance, it is generally more computationally intensive to evaluate $p(x)$ for integers $x$ large in magnitude than ones small in magnitude, in which case working from largest to smallest need not be optimal.)

Checking shows that $r(8), r(4) \neq 0$, and so any integer roots of $r$ are $1$, $2$. On the other hand, for any polynomial $p$, the product of the roots (counting multiplicity) is $(-1)^{\deg p} a_0$. So if we know in advance that all of the roots of $q$ are integers, so are all the roots $b_j$ of $r$, and if the multiplicity of $2$ as a root of $r$ is $k$, the multiplicity of $1$ is $5 - k$, and by the above we have that $-(-8) = 1^{5 - k} 2^k = 2^k$. Thus, $k = 3$, and so we conclude that
$$q(x) = (x - 6) (x - 2)^3 (x - 1)^2 $$
as desired. Note that this method only required evaluating a polynomial $8$ times and a carrying out a single polynomial long division (and again, knowing in advance that all of the roots of $p$ were integers).

**Caution** Several of the techniques here can only be applied when the given polynomial has certain properties. Most importantly, (1) not all roots of a real polynomial need be rational (indeed, none need be, as is the case for $x^2 - 2$), and (2) not all roots of a real polynomial need even be real (as in the case of $x^2 + 1$), and correspondingly, a polynomial need not be factorable over $\Bbb R$. In general, factoring a polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$ is difficult and/or labor-intensive (and in the latter case there's a question of what form one wants). See the Wikipedia article, [*Factorization of Polynomials*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials), for more information.

Comment: I think maybe I need to get my definitions straight first. A real polynomial is a polynomial with real numbers like $4$, $\sqrt{3}$, $5/7$, etc, correct? A rational polynomial is one with coefficients in form $p/q$ for integers $p,q$, and an integer polynomial is one with only integer coefficients. I'm guessing a complex polynomial is one with complex coefficients. Is this right so far? If so, what do we know about the (possible) roots / factors of each type? I got lost a little when you talked about the alternating signs and the last paragraph.

Comment: Yes, a real polynomial has real coefficients, a rational polynomial has rational coefficients, etc. One can make some general statements in the real case, e.g., for a real polynomial, nonreal roots come in conjugate pairs, and so the number of real roots (counting multiplicity) has the same parity as the degree of the polynomial; concordantly, any real polynomial factors as a product of linear and quadratic real polynomials. No such statement holds when factoring a rational polynomial over $\Bbb Q$; indeed, there are irreducible polynomials of arbitrary degree.

Comment: The key observation about alternating signs is that, if a polynomial $p(x)$ has alternating signs, then the coefficients of $p(-x)$ all have the same sign. In particular, this means that the function has the same (nonzero) sign on $[0, \infty)$ as it does at $0$. So, $p(-x)$ has no positive roots, but a positive root of $p(-x)$ is the same thing as a negative root of $p(x)$. In conclusion: If the signs of $p(x)$ alternate, all of its roots are positive.

Comment: Does this relate to Sturm's Theorem, which I recall had something to do with counting real vs. complex roots by looking at the alternating signs? Or are you referring to something different?

Comment: Yes, it is related, but the conclusions of the two lines of reasoning are different.

Comment: So if you look at any arbitrary polynomial, is it possible to tell 1. how many roots it has and of what type, and 2. their multiplicities?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33945/discussion-between-travis-and-aruka-j).

Answer (score 0):

If you will accept a "brain-dead" method, why not just appeal to computer algebra, such as *Mathematica*?

```
Factor[x^6 - 14 x^5 + 73 x^4 - 188 x^3 + 256 x^2 - 176 x^1 + 48]
```

$(x-6) (x-2)^3 (x-1)^2$

or

```
Factor[-20284203008 + 12410729472 x + 2524112000 x^2 - 
  1341562640 x^3 - 334176180 x^4 + 12601652 x^5 + 12198347 x^6 + 
  1767405 x^7 + 127690 x^8 + 5150 x^9 + 111 x^10 + x^11]
```

$(x-4) (x-2)^2 (x+8)^3 (x+19)^5$

Comment: I want to be able to do it on paper / by hand if I needed to. I know how to use Mathematica / Wolfram Alpha to do it for me, but I'd like to know how to do it myself.

Comment: Or ask [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E6-14x%5E5%2B73x%5E4-188x%5E3%2B256x%5E2-176x%5E1%2B48).

Comment: Mathematica's `Factor` function isn't always as "brain-dead": for example, `Factor[x^2-2]` will output $-2+x^2$...

Comment: @A.P.  `Factor` isn't "brain-dead."  Because it "factors a polynomial *over the integers*" it indeed gives the correct result for the case you post.

Comment: I'm fully aware of that, as you can see by reading the last part of my answer. My qualm is with how you phrased your question: the OP asked for "a methodical, algorithmic, brain-dead way to factor polynomials", and you wrote "[i]f you will accept a "brain-dead" method, why not just appeal to computer algebra, such as Mathematica?"
This seems to suggest that `Factor` is a fire-and-forget function for factoring polynomials, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Since in your comments you mention that you would like to apply polynomial factorization to the study of linear recurrences, I assume that you are looking for a general algorithm to factor a polynomial over $\Bbb{C}$ (cfr. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1592813/65389)). You can always factor over $\Bbb{Z}$ a reducible polynomial with integer coefficients, but there isn't any general way to find the complex roots of an irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}[X]$, let alone a "brain-dead" one. Thus I'm going to propose a simple algorithm to obtain a *partial* factorization.

First, recall that every polynomial with complex coefficients factors completely over $\Bbb{C}$ as a product of polynomials of degree $1$, and that $r$ is a root of a polynomial $f(X)$ if and only if $X-r \mid f(X)$. This means that the problem of factoring a polynomial over $\Bbb{C}$ is equivalent to finding its (complex) roots. So here's what you can always do, given a polynomial $f(X) \in \Bbb{C}[X]$:

1. Define empty lists $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda'$.
2. If $f(X)$ has integer coefficients, compute any rational roots (e.g. with a greedy algorithm based on the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), see Travis's answer).

   - Add them to $\Lambda$.
   - Continue with $f'(X) = f(X) / \prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} (X - \lambda)$.
3. If $\deg f' = 0$ jump to the last step.
4. If $\deg f' \leq 4$ compute its roots using the appropriate formula by radicals.

   - Add them to $\Lambda$.
   - Set $f'(X) = 1$ and jump to the last step.
5. *Optional*: Use your favourite numerical method(s) to approximate the roots of $f'(X)$.

   - Add them to $\Lambda'$.
6. Output $f'(X) \prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} (X - \lambda)$ and $\Lambda'$.

*Note 1:* There are some sophisticated algorithms to [factor a polynomial over the integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials#Factoring_univariate_polynomials_over_the_integers) which you could use instead of point 2. Then you'd have to repeat points 3 to 5 for every non-linear factor you find.

*Note 2:* If you're bent to venture outside the algebraic realm, you can add a step 4' to look for an *analytic* closed-form expression of the roots of [quintic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Beyond_radicals) and [sextic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SexticEquation.html) polynomials.

*Note 3:* In some cases it may be possible to determine algorithmically if the Galois group of (the splitting field of) $f'$ is [solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group) and, if it is, find the roots of $f'$ by radicals. This was done for [sextic polynomials](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186930098428X), but I'm not aware of more general results.

---

As far as I know, polynomial factorization in Mathematica (and, by extension, in WolframAlpha) revolves around the aptly-named [`Factor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factor.html?q=Factor) function. This function factors a polynomial over the ring of algebraic integers of a user-specified [number field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field), and it defaults to factoring over $\Bbb{Z}$. You can use it only for step 2 above, like I mentioned in *note 1*.

You can also use [Solve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve) to find the roots of a generic polynomial of degree $\leq 4$ and those of a few polynomials of higher degree, but that's it as far as exact methods go.

For example, WolframAlpha will produce only numerical approximations for the roots of [$x^5-4x+2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5%2D4x%2B2) and for those of [$x^7+x+1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E7%2Bx%2B1).